# Best practices: one or separate servers for development and production websites?

Tags: apache, web, development-environment

Is it better to have:

- One server for both development websites (dev.test.com) and production websites (www.test.com)

OR

- Two servers - one for development websites (dev.test.com) and one for production websites (www.test.com)

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, I prefer to have separate servers for production and development websites. My reasons are as follows:

- On occasion, a developer may commit code that introduces a security vulnerability. I have seen this happen in a way that resulted in a server being root kitted. Fortunately, since production ran on a different server, the problem was isolated and didn't affect clients.
- Having separate servers makes it easier to see the effects of upgrading to a newer version of software, or implementing a new service without affecting running services in production.
- If you regularly "reset" your development environment to mirror your production one, it also serves as an additional backup of sorts.

If you have limited resources, you could potentially set up virtual machines on a single physical host to achieve the same end result.